# php to check the existence of two fields in the database, using JSON

Tags: java, php, android, json, phpmyadmin

in the 'user' table I put customers registered, and to access to the menu you must login so I need a verification the client, that with php and using Json.
but it does not work

this is l'activité loginActivity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    final EditText txtNumCompte = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtNumCompte);
    final EditText txtCodCompte = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtCodCompte);
    Button btnLogin = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String numcompte = txtNumCompte.getText().toString();
            String codecompte = txtCodCompte.getText().toString();
            if (numcompte.equals("") || codecompte.equals(""))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Numéro et code confidentiel de compte sont obligatoires",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".[0-9]+");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(numcompte);
            if (m.matches() == false)
            {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,
                    "La carte est non trouvée \nVeuillez vérifier son numéro",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }
            try{
                HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,
                    TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
                HttpParams d = new BasicHttpParams();
                d.setParameter("user", "1");

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(d);
                String url = "http://10.0.2.2/connect.php";
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

                try {
                    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "send  task - start");
                    //
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user", "1"));
                    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                    String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost,
                        responseHandler);

                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseBody);
                    JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("posts");

                    for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject e = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String s = e.getString("post");
                        if(s!=null) a=a+1;
                    }

                    if(a==0)
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Connecté avec succès", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Intent intent= new Intent(LoginActivity.this,MenuActivity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else{
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Numéro/code confidentiel invalide", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"dsl , probleme de connexion",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"dsl , probleme dans le serveur , essayez autre fois",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

this is connct.php

>

```
 <?php
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);
$con = mysql_connect('localhost','root','') or die('Cannot connect to the DB');
mysql_select_db('baseandroid',$con);
$sql = 'SELECT count(*) FROM user WHERE Num_Compte=".$obj->{'num'}.'" AND Code_Compte="'.$obj->{'code'}.'"'; 
$req = mysql_query($sql) ;
$data = mysql_fetch_array($req); 
mysql_free_result($req); 
  $query = "SELECT * FROM Compte where Num_Compte=".$obj->{'num'}."";
  $result = mysql_query($query,$con) ;
 /* create one master array of the records */
   if(mysql_num_rows($result)) {
    while($post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $posts[] = array('post'=>$post);
    }
  }
 @mysql_close($con);
  header('Content-type: application/json'); 
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, you are using network on the UI Thread. This is wrong. use an AsyncTask to do that.

Then, 'it does not work' is not a very helpful description of the problem. Can you start the connection? Do you have any exception? Do you see the connection on the server? Do you have some data in the connection? Do you receive an answer? what is in the answer?

Comment: No , I don't have any exception , but how can i see the connection on the server please? what's you mean?

Comment: don't you have, like, and access log on your web server? anyway, start with putting all the network outside the UI Thread. It will raise an exception on 3.0+

Comment: please give me an example, I didn't understand howa i put outside the UI Thread, and howa i use use an AsyncTask.

Comment: plenty of example everywhere, including, but not restricted to, http://developer.android.com